# Organizing Spring Boot profiles into directories

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot project with a handful of different configurations we use and these are based on profiles. This has worked great for me so far but the issue is I'm getting quite a bit of profiles in the `resources` directory. I would like to organize them into directories so they are easier to locate quickly. I've tried doing that but when moving them into nested directories Spring fails to actually load the values of the given profiles.

Ex structure:

```
resources
  database
    application-liqudbase.yaml
    application-embedded.yaml
  environments
    application-test.yaml
    application-prod.yaml
```

In this example I would set `test.yaml` to have a `spring.profiles.include: database/embedded.yaml` for instance. This issue is this does not load the values in the `embedded.yaml` file even though no errors are thrown. Is this possible at all using the default Spring profile setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you're looking for is the property, `spring.config.location`.  It's a comma-separated list of directories to locate your configuration files.  In your example above it would be `spring.config.location=classpath:/database/,classpath:/environments/`

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files for more information.

Comment: This worked great! I can't believe I didn't see it in the documentation as I was reading that page right before posting the question... thanks a bunch. And for anyone trying to do this in Spring Boot using Gradle I ended up adding it to the `bootRun` task's `jvmArgs` so it's constant for the project.